# Is there a way to concat this base url with list, I've tried literally everything possible for to no avail

Tags: python, list, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to get data from several URLs, having the same base URL. This is my code:

```
path = 'C:/ChromerDriver/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path, options=options)
    
link_list = ['/organization/4m-carbon-fiber', '/organization/aeropowder' ,'/organization/algiknit']
    
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
df = pd.DataFrame()
    
urls = driver.get('https://www.crunchbase.com'.join(link_list))
    
for url in urls:
    try:
        name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[contains(@class, "profile-name")]').text
        website = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class = "component--field-formatter layout-row layout-align-start-end link-accent ng-star-inserted"]').get_attribute('href')
        logo = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/chrome/div/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav-content/div/ng-component/entity-v2/page-layout/div/div/profile-header/div/header/div/div/div/div[1]/identifier-image/div/img').get_attribute('src')
    except:
        time.sleep(5)

df = df.append(pd.DataFrame({'name' : name, 
                            'website' : website, 
                            'logo' : logo}, 
                            index = [0]), ignore_index = True) 
      
df.to_csv('raw_data.csv', index=False)
```

How should I combine `link_list` with the base URL properly?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "concat these url with list". What is supposed to happen when you run the code? What does happen, and how is that different?

Comment: In particular, where you have `urls = driver.get('https://www.crunchbase.com'.join(link_list))`, what are you expecting `urls` to look like after that?

Comment: Yes, that's it @KarlKnechtel

Comment: **link_list = ['/organization/4m-carbon-fiber', '/organization/aeropowder' ,'/organization/algiknit']** @KarlKnechtel

Comment: Okay, well then `driver.get` obviously has nothing to do with it, right? That shouldn't happen until you are inside the `for url in urls` loop, right? Makes sense? Since you want to do something *separate* with the `driver`, `for` each of the `url` values that is `in urls`, yeah?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
urls = ['https://www.crunchbase.com' + elem for elem in link_list]
 
for url in urls:
    try:
        resp = driver.get(url)
        ...
```

Also, place df.append() inside the for-loop if you want to append all results and not only the last one.